# Saving Multiple Annotations -NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, mkannotation

I came cross this code as shown below.In the following code, I could able to save only one single annotation, however I have an array of annotations, I could not able to save them with single NSUserDefaults

```
  To save:

    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [ud setDouble:location.latitude forKey:@"savedCoordinate-latitude"];
    [ud setDouble:location.longitude forKey:@"savedCoordinate-longitude"];
    [ud setBool:YES forKey:@"savedCoordinate-exists"];
    [ud synchronize];
```

Edited:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
        NSUserDefaults *ud=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            if([ud boolForKey:@"save-exist"])
            { NSMutableArray *udAnnotations=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:
[ud objectForKey:@"annotationsArray"]];
                NSLog(@"%d",[udAnnotations count]);
            }
            else{
            [self addAnno];
            }

    -(void)addAnno
    {

    [mapView addAnnotations:annotationArray];
    NSUserDefaults *ud=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [ud setObject:annotationArray forKey:@"annotationsArray"];
    [ud setBool:YES forKey:@"save-exist"];
    [ud synchronize];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have an array, simply use `setObject:forKey:` and `arrayForKey:`

As the objects in your original array are not a type that can be saved directly, store their data in dictionaries:

```
NSMutableArray *saveData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:originalData.count];
for(id location in originalData) {
    [saveData addObject:@{@"lat":[location latitude], @"lon":[location longitude]}];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:saveData forKey:@"annotationsArray"];
```

and convert on retrieval:

```
NSMutableArray *restoredData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSDictionary *data in [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"annotationsArray"]) {
    [restoredData addObject:[[Location alloc] initWithLat:data[@"lat"] andLon:data[@"lon"]]];
}
// if restoredData.count is 0, there were no stored objects.
```

A couple notes:

- If you're not using ARC, remember to release the alloc'd objects.
- This uses the new objective c object literal syntax and dictionary access syntax. If you aren't using xcode 4.5 you'll need to construct and access them the traditional way, `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` and `objectForKey:`

Comment: Hello Kevin, I am really appreciated that your answer. i have just implemented the way that you described, but it does not give me back my mutable array. I have just posted my original code under the edited  part. I don't know why I am getting O objects while I am getting back my array!! any idea?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:) , the elements of the array must be property list objects, so you may have to convert them to, e.g., dictionaries before storing, and convert back when reading them out.

Comment: thanks a lot Kevin. Do you know any documents, how could I convert NSMutableArray to dictionaries?

Comment: It's not the array you need to convert, you need to convert the annotations to dictionaries. I've added an example.